# What is the RSK correspondence for $G\wr S_n.$

Tags: co.combinatorics, robinson-schensted-knuth

What is the RSK correspondence for $G\wr S_n$?. Where can I read about this?

Comment: There seems to be a general result of this type in a paper by Soichi Okada dx.doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(90)90044-W

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219904/what-is-the-rsk-correspondence-for-g-wr-s-n

Comment: voted to close since it is rude to crosspost.